# play .mp4 video in jsp page which is not located in tomcat directory

Tags: java, jsp, video

I am trying to play a video from a different location `(/var/songs/)`.
In my jsp I am using code like:

```
<embed src="${path}" type="application/x-mplayer2" 
       pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" 
       name="mediaplayer1" ShowStatusBar="true" EnableContextMenu="false" 
       width="700" height="500" autostart="false" loop="false" align="middle" 
       volume="60" />
```

where `${path}=/var/songs/ab.mp4`

But this code is not working

Comment: What does your access log say of the URL `http://your.server/var/songs/ab.mp4`? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved it by putting songs folder inside apache directory.So the url become localhost/songs/ab.mp4. It is working fine.so by calling this url from java program video starts playing.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's not working is the fact that the browser will read the embed. So the browser expects a remotely reachable URL.

What you could do is create a servlet which you map on `/songs` in your web.xml.

Something like:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>SongsServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.example.SongsServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SongsServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/songs/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now the request could then be something like `http://somedomain:8080/songs/ab.mp4`

Now this servlet reads a file based on the path coming from the request and maps it to `/var/songs`.

That should do the trick.

Comment: I am working on struts 2.1.In struts.xml I have given an entry like <action name="showVideo" class="com.action.Video" >
            <result name="success">video.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">index.jsp</result>                         
        </action>.In Video class I am giving the path like /var/songs/ab.mp4 and fetching it in jsp using src=${path}.so my complete url is http://localhost:8084/videourl/showVideo?id=ab.mp4.But still not able to play video in jsp

Comment: @ Jeroen,Please help.what should be the code inside SongServlet to map the path?Do I need to use FileInputStream class but I don't want to download.I just want to play video on any web browser.